# Create a list of lists stored as objects in a single column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have lists stored as objects in a column of data. I need to create a single list from these 'lists' but they are not being recognized as a list.

I have tried converting column to a list, concatenating, creating a series but the results are not treated as a list.

What I have:

```
code1
Out[83]: 
0    ['hair', 'body']
1    ['hair', 'body']
2    ['hair', 'body']
Name: personal_interests, dtype: object

code1.tolist()
Out[79]: ["['hair', 'body']", "['hair', 'body']", "['hair', 'body']"]
```

What I need:

```
example = [['hair', 'body'],
           ['hair', 'body'],
           ['hair', 'body']]
example
Out[94]: [['hair', 'body'], ['hair', 'body'], ['hair', 'body']]
```

Comment: maybe there is string, not list, but it looks on screen like list.

Comment: I created DF with lists in cells and `tolist()` gives me list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution evaluates the list inside the string and appends to a new empty list:

```
from ast import literal_eval
l1 = ["['hair', 'body']", "['hair', 'body']", "['hair', 'body']"]
l2 = []
for i in l1:
    l2.append(literal_eval(i))
l2 
#[['hair', 'body'], ['hair', 'body'], ['hair', 'body']]
```

I tried to reproduce the problem by passing the lists as strings instead of pure lists:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'a':["['hair', 'body']", "['hair', 'body']"]})
df
        a
0   ['hair', 'body']
1   ['hair', 'body']
```

As you will notice, the elements in the dataframe do not show as strings but as normal lists. When I convert the series to list, the elements are represented as strings, as expected:

```
df['a'].tolist()
#["['hair', 'body']", "['hair', 'body']"]
```

So now if we `apply` literal_eval on all elements and then convert to list, we get the desired results.

```
df['a'].apply(literal_eval).tolist()
#[['hair', 'body'], ['hair', 'body']]
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the pointers, not familiar with the ast package but I will be sure to take a look at it now. Thanks amanb!

Comment: You're welcome. I also tried to reproduce the problem and it appears that the original elements would have been created as strings instead of lists. Something like this: `df= pd.DataFrame({'a':["['hair', 'body']", "['hair', 'body']"]})` and with such a `df` I can reproduce the problem. However, if these were lists originally, then it gives the expected output. Can you also show how the dataframe is created in the first place?

Comment: It was in .csv format and imported. Maybe there is a way when importing to treat the column as lists.

Comment: In pandas, `read_csv` is the recommended function to read csv files. It could be possible that the data in the csv was strings instead of lists, in the first place.